# Unable to assign session value to varibale in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, session

I am assigning a set of values to `session` i.e. `search data` retrieved through `ajax`  in `nodejs` application as below:

```
req.session.searchData=result.GetSearchDataResult;
```

and when any of the rendered record is clicked user will be redirected to new `view` and in server I am loading different data relating to that clicked record. I am passing `id` as url parameter and I am planning to get the record from stored `session.searchData` by filtering. But even though the values are present in `session.searchData`, I am not able to assign it to any variable to read the value and filter.

When I console.log `req.session.searchData` below is what I get:

```
{"lstDetails":
     [
      {"ID":"FFSDER2da2411cDSs12CGh21",
       "FirstName":"Test",
       "LastName":"Data",
       "DOB":"8/15/1921 12:00:00 AM",
       "AddressLine1":"Test Address Line 1",
       "AddressLine2":"",
       "City":"FakeCity",
       "State":"ST",
       "Zip":"41511",
       "PID":0,
       "EmailID":"SC4239925@FakeEmail.com",
       "Gender":"1",
       "WorkPhone":"",
       "OtherPhone":"5555555555",
       "ICarier":
                  {"ICName":null,
                  "IGName":null,
                  "IGNum":null
                  }
       },
       {"ID":"DS24DASD5da21afd56D4#2!",
       "FirstName":"Test2",
       "LastName":"Data2",
       "DOB":"8/15/1921 12:00:00 AM",
       "AddressLine1":"Test2 Address Line 1",
       "AddressLine2":"",
       "City":"FakeCity2",
       "State":"ST2",
       "Zip":"41511",
       "PID":0,
       "EmailID":"SC4239925@FakeEmail.com",
       "Gender":"1",
       "WorkPhone":"",
       "OtherPhone":"5555555555",
       "ICarier":
                  {"ICName":null,
                  "IGName":null,
                  "IGNum":null
                  }
       }
     ]
}
```

But when I try to assign it to a variable, its always **`undefined`**

```
app.use(session({secret: 'secretkey'}));
console.log(req.session.searchData); //this prints above list values
var patientArray = req.session.searchData; 
console.log("Patient Array - " +patientArray); //this prints "Patient Array - undefined"
```

I also tried using `app.get` as below but with no luck.

```
var patientArray;
app.get("/",function(req,res){
  var sess=req.session;
  patientArray=sess.searchData; //never enters here
});
console.log(patientArray);
```

But above method is never called.

What am I missing here? How can I read session values and assign it to a variable?

Comment: Can't find any issue in the code you've posted. Can you please post the full function.

Comment: @Darshan, Its a huge one.. a complete application, I just gave the basic details of what's happening.. There should be something to be done with `session` and I am not sure what is that..

Comment: Are those first four statements in the same function?

Comment: @Darshan Yes, they are..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `req.session.searchData=result.GetSearchDataResult;` used to return `json-response`, the same `json-response` was getting stored in `req.session.searchData`. Not sure whether this is correct behavior,  but then I had to use `JSON.parse(req.session.searchData);` to get proper data.